# How to set timezone with moment?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

i am using moment for getting server time .

```
moment.tz.setDefault("Asia/Kolkata");

var now = new Date();
var _p_date = moment.tz(now, zone).format();
```

time when inserting _p_date = **2016-01-05T18:32:00+05:30**
But in database date variable is type of **DATETIME**. and time is saved as 2016-01-05 18:32:00.
and after that when i comparing with this to get time_ago funcionality. providing me wrong estimation.

using time ago =  `moment("2016-01-05T18:32:00.000Z").fromNow();`  // is showing **In 5 hours**

Comment: Have you tried moment.tz(moment("2016-01-05T18:32:00.000Z"), "Asia/Kolkata").fromNow(); ?

Comment: yes, but not helpful. same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your initial timezone is lost you have to create moment.tz object with selected timezone. Try this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DRVHEuyCEcMPLJOeuke8)

```
var date = moment.tz(moment("2016-01-05T18:32:00.000Z", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm")
    .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'), 'Asia/Kolkata');


console.log(date.fromNow());
```

Comment: throwing in a loop. like moment.tz(moment(result[i].created, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'), 'Asia/Kolkata').fromNow(); is showing "Invalid date" . // result[i].created = "2016-01-05T17:23:47.000Z".

Comment: check plunker again. I created array with few dates and it's working just fine. and I live in your timezone :)

Comment: OMG , just print in console.log(result[i].created); is showing Tue Jan 05 2016 17:23:47 GMT+0000 (UTC) and when i pass it showing 2016-01-05T17:23:47.000Z. whats wrong with this....

Comment: how we can change the text to our liking like a few seconds ago to a sec ago or a few minutes ago to a mins ago.. etc.

Comment: fromNow() will format them automatically "0 to 45 seconds" - a few seconds ago, "45 to 90 seconds" - a minute ago etc. If you need time only to be show in seconds or minutes you can calculate diff in milliseconds and use moment-duration lib or math. Also don't forget to add seconds to format.

Comment: tried with some new Date() and matches seconds but result is different bcz new Date() refered to another timezone. can code me for this? change text for seconds ago or minutes ago or hours ago or days ago.? expecting +ve response

Comment: Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/QOtQx0MffqXt01YuFlI9 . And tell me if this is what you wanted.